# Setting JAVA_HOME not working in Sierra

Tags: macos, java

I have following versions of Java:

```
$ /usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (4):
    9.0.1, x86_64:  "Java SE 9.0.1" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_131, x86_64:  "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_121, x86_64:  "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.7.0_80, x86_64:   "Java SE 7" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Then I want to set Java version to 1.7:

```
$ JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Seems OK, but:

```
$ java -version
java version "9.0.1"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.1+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.1+11, mixed mode)
```

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set `JAVA_HOME`, you should use

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v "1.7*"`
```

or

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home
```

currently you  did not use `export` on the variable. Environment variables that are set without the `export` command will not be inherited in the environment of the commands you are calling, so it would not be read by Java.